# How to implement a procedural macro, which allows assigning values to fields？

Tags: rust, macros

Is there any way to change this:

```rust
struct A<'a> {
    foo: u8,
    bar: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Default for A<'a> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            foo: 123,
            bar: "abc",
        }
    }
}
```

To this:

```rust
#[...]
struct A<'a> {
    foo: u8 = 123,
    bar: &'a str = "abc",
}
```

Theoretically, a procedure macro has the ability to automatically generate functions, but I don't know how to write it.

Comment: You can certainly do this. Procedural macros can emit any Rust syntax items you want, including a modified struct definition, additional implementations, or anything else. But I'd probably think it's not worth it to do so, unless you have a _ton_ of these types, or if you just want to learn about proc-macros. I'd recommend the [little book](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/introduction.html) if if you want to learn more.

Comment: @Aplet123 Proc macro definitely _can_ alter the definition of the item. Only derive macros can't. However, they can't consume invalid Rust syntax.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible because this is not a valid Rust syntax, and attribute-like procedural macros cannot inspect invalid Rust syntax.

You have two options:

1. Use a function-like procedural macro, which *is* able to inspect and alter invalid syntax:

   ```rust
   my_macro! {
       struct A<'a> {
           foo: u8 = 123,
           bar: &'a str = "abc",
       }
   }
   ```

   I don't know of any crate that has that, but you can write your own (and it doesn't even have to be a procedural macro).
2. Use attributes for the default value:

   ```rust
   #[derive(SmartDefault)]
   struct A<'a> {
       #[default = 123]
       foo: u8,
       #[default = "abc"]
       bar: &'a str,
   }
   ```

   There is a crate that does exactly that: [`smart-default`](https://docs.rs/smart-default/latest/smart_default/derive.SmartDefault.html).